# Sending chosen information from JSP to a servlet when a hyper link is clicked

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, jstl

I'm using a JSP page that displays a list of "festival names". I want to then link to a page on click which will show the "profile page" of that festival. how do i send which link was clicked to the JAVA SERVLET so that i can use SQL and Java to send the chosen information to the "profile page" jsp.

```
<table border ="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Festival Name:</td>
            <td>Location:</td>
            <td>Start Date:</td>
            <td>End Date:</td>
            <td>URL:</td>
            <td>List of Trips to </td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${allFestivals}" var="festival">
        <tr>      
            <td>${festival.festivalName}</td>
            <td>${festival.location}</td>
            <td>${festival.startDate}</td>
            <td>${festival.endDate}</td>
            <td>${festival.URL}</td>
            <td><a href="festival_profile.jsp">View Your Festivals</a></td>
             ^i have the festivals ID that can be sent with this link in the jsp
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

I simple need to know how to send the chosen "festival" ID back to the servlet so it can generate the profile JSP. EDIT : and how to catch it on the servlet

Comment: We have an excellent wiki on `servlets`, check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the link

```
<a href="<c:url value="/servletpath"><c:param name="id" value="${festival.id}"/></c:url>">View Your Festivals</a>
```

Comment: Where is that "name=id value="${festival.id}" sent to/how do i catch it. (i assume it is sent to the servlet)

Comment: It's a typo "id" sure you send it to the servlet where you could catch with `request.getParameter("id")`

Comment: but to user "request." it would have to be inside a method. how to i get that method running to "request" in the first palce". Sorry if this is ignorant. Appreciate the help.

Comment: when you click on the link then request is sent to the servlet. Inside the method you get the `request`.

Comment: @JackDalton Inside the `doGet(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)` method.

Comment: http://imgur.com/bNqRaAI
http://imgur.com/lTolPUV
this just a generic action to keep it simple. If i wanted to print out the name of the festival that had it's link clicked. What would i put? Linked my current code.