# Sending a Value from JSP to a servlet

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets, href

I have a list of objects in a JSP and want to send a value back to the servlet based on a hyperlink that was clicked. My code is show bellow.

```
<body>
    <h1>Choose a Festival</h1>
    <jsp:useBean id="allFestivals" type="java.util.ArrayList" scope="session" />
    <table border ="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Festival Name:</td>
            <td>Location:</td>
            <td>Start Date:</td>
            <td>End Date:</td>
            <td>URL:</td>
            <td>List of Trips to </td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${allFestivals}" var="allFestivals">
        <tr>      
            <td>${allFestivals.festivalName}</td>
            <td>${allFestivals.location}</td>
            <td>${allFestivals.startDate}</td>
            <td>${allFestivals.endDate}</td>
            <td>${allFestivals.URL}</td>
            <td>
                //THE ISSUE IS IN THIS FORM, I SUPPOSE SYNTAX ISSUE
                <form name="linkChecker" method="get" action="ControllerServlet">
                    <input type = "hidden" value="${allFestivals.ID}" name="festivalProfileLink" /> 
                    <a HREF ="javascript:document.linkChecker.submit()">View Related Trips</a>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table> 

<a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a>

</body>
```

and servlet GET method:

```
 @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException  {

    String aa = request.getParameter("festivalProfileLink");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, aa);
    if("hello".equals(aa)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "dfgdfgdf");
    }
 }
```

at the moment no information (or at least no value) is being sent to the servlet

Answer (score 1):

You are making a POST request you will not get result in `doGet()` try in `doPost()`

edit in answer based on edit on your post

for this type of operation GET is well suited you could just generate link

as suggested [here in your earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840506/sending-chosen-information-from-jsp-to-a-servlet-when-a-hyper-link-is-clicked) you should generate link that would pass parameter
by URL

with this approach I suspect you are posting at wrong path you could investigate it using firebug

Comment: Very well spotted, answers like this are why SO is so great.

Comment: sorry that was a typo, and no this does not work with "get" (i've edited the origonal post")

Comment: @Jigar I also have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368770/how-to-iterate-an-object-in-jsp-to-get-the-percentage). See if you can help me out? Any help will be appreciated on that.. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Using a JOptionPane within a Servlet is really weird -- instead just log something.